# What is the difference between $$foo vs ${$foo} for dynamic PHP variable names?

Tags: php

What is the difference between `$$foo` and `${$foo}` for dynamic PHP variable names?
For Example:

```
$foo = 'Something';
$bar = 'foo';
echo $$bar , PHP_EOL; // Something
echo ${$bar} , PHP_EOL; // Something
```

Are there any differences between these two syntax except the second one can use a value returned from a function directly.
Is one better than the other?

Comment: `${$bar}` can be inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that pops into my mind is when using **inline curly syntax** <sup>[Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)</sup>.

---

Consider the following example:

```php
<?php

$foo = 'Something';
$bar = 'foo';

echo "$$bar" . PHP_EOL; // $foo
echo "${$bar}" . PHP_EOL; // Something
```

<sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLSyUtP1/BVkE9OD83tSQjMy9d3ZpLJSmxCCQGlALyuFKTM/IVlFRAokoKegoBHgHxrv4@1gr6@gog3TD5apCCWnQVcHO5/v8HAA)</sup>

---

Here the first `echo "$$bar"` wont work as expected because PHP doesn't parse it as a variable variable.